# How to Update collaborator permission from admin to pull (Read) using github api?

Tags: github, github-api

I'm trying to update the permission of collaborators across all repos in a Github Organisation. The collaborators are also Organisation members. I want to change permisssion from admin to pull (read). Unable to do so using the github api (v3). Tried with the go package `github.com/google/go-github/v28/github` and also CURL like mentioned in the [doc](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/rest/reference/collaborators#add-a-repository-collaborator) . Got 204 No Content Response but the changes did not happen.

```
curl -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" https://github.com/api/v3/repos/$ORG/$REPO/collaborators/$USER -X PUT -d '{"permission":"pull"}'
```

Is there any other better way to change the collaborator permissions from admin to pull ?

*Please note: the same api allows to change the permission if they are Outside Collaborators (non organisation members)*